# Lifetime of object when allocated in the DispatchQueue (Swift)

Tags: swift, closures, out-of-memory, allocation

I am sending images very fast using a DispatchQueue, and while resulting images are small, to generate one first I have to generate a large Bitmap (8 Mb).

The problem is that when sending is too fast, the app crashes because of memory consumption. When I check it with instruments, I see that before crash, about 30 bitmaps are still allocated (240 Mb total!).

But why? With Swift's reference counting I would expect bitmap object to be deallocated at the exit of closure, no?

```
DispatchQueue(label: "Queue").async{

    let bitmap = generateBitmap()
}
```

Comment: Update: there are two queues in original code. First, where image data is captured is running on DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background). Then it calls the code above, which is a separate queue because bitmap processing takes time. And we have this out of memory problem here. 

Now if for experiment, I do all processing on first thread, not changing anything else, then the problem is gone! Huge bitmap objects are not left undeallocated, they even do not appear in instrument's allocations.

Answer (score 1):

wrap your utilization of the bitmap in a @autoreleasepool:

```
DispatchQueue(label: "Queue").async {

    var generatedImage: UIImage?
    @autoreleasepool {
        let bitmap = generateBitmap()
        generatedImage = makeSmallImage(from: bitmap)
    }
    //... use your generatedImage as you see fit.  The bitmap is already released from memory at this point and is no longer retained.
}
```

Please note however that this assumes the image you create doesn't retain the bitmap used as source.  You could confirm that by subclassing the bitmap class and verifying its deinit() function gets called.

Comment: Autorelease did not help at first. :/ At the critical moment bitmaps are created in 100 ms interval.

Comment: Instead of constantly creating new dispatch queue, you may want to create a single dispatch queue, keep a reference to it, then dispatch tasks to that queue every 100ms.  Make sure to keep that @autorelease block in there.

Comment: If you notice that they are now happening properly, no longer running out of memory but they don't execute every 100ms, you might need to optimize your bitmap generation code.  If you run a task every 100ms, that task should not take more than 50ms total if you want to keep things running relatively smooth.

Answer (score 0):

ARC will indicate which object should be released from memory, but it doesn't remove that object itself.
check your queue priority, maybe CPU doesn't find any time to take care of releasing objectts

Comment: That might be a root cause (see my new comment to the original post). I am using .userInitiated in the original setup. Tried to change it to .background  - does not help. But it works if I do everything on DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background) - except thus I slow down processing.